# Failed to fetch error while downloading wine in different country

Tags: apt, server, updates, wine

I set up my computer in the USA, so my sources.list file is the default USA sources.list. I am, however, now based in mainland China. I am trying to install wine using the command

```
sudo apt install wine
```

but I get the following 'failed to fetch' errors:

```
Err:1 https://deepin-wine.i-m.dev  libsasl2-modules-db 2.1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:da8:d800:95::110 443]
Err:2 https://deepin-wine.i-m.dev  libsasl2-2 2.1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:da8:d800:95::110 443]
Err:3 https://deepin-wine.i-m.dev  libsasl2-modules 2.1.28+dfsg-6ubuntu2        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:da8:d800:95::110 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cyrus-sasl2/libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.28%2bdfsg-6ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:da8:d800:95::110 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cyrus-sasl2/libsasl2-2_2.1.28%2bdfsg-6ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:da8:d800:95::110 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cyrus-sasl2/libsasl2-modules_2.1.28%2bdfsg-6ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:da8:d800:95::110 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

(I am actually currently based at USTC, but I think its just a coincidence that those mirrors are hosted here.) I checked the mirrors site https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cyrus-sasl2/, and it is true that none of those files that ubuntu is trying to fetch are there anymore. I figure I could fix this by changing the filenames in the sources.list file, but my sources.list file is just the default 20.04 USA version (everything gets from the us.archive.ubuntu.com servers), so I am not sure why my machine is going to the USTC mirrors. I cannot find the source file for these links.

I then tried to run the same download while using a USA VPN, but I have the same issue: it still tries to go to the USTC mirrors and can't find them, and the download fails.

So my question is, how can I fix this failed to fetch error?

Here is my version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

(I tried apt-get update and using --fix-missing, but it had the same results)

Comment: I doubt you can do anything about the broken mirrors. In case you know where to find the IT staff, talk to them. As a simple workaround, select another mirror.

Comment: How do I select another mirror? I can't find the file on my machine that is specifying these particular mirrors in the first place.

Comment: There is an obvious way to use the GUI tool, point and click, and it is done. I wouldn't select a US one while being in China though.